# Convert spark dataframe to json using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in the following format

```
ID  currency   account name    principal   interest
123    USD     Principal       1000        100
123    EUR     Principal       2000        50
123    USD     Interest        2000        100
```

I would like the json output in the following format :

```
{ 
       "id":"123",
       "principal_type":{ 
          "USD":1000,
          "EUR":2000
       },
       "interest_type":{ 
          "USD":100
       }
    }
```

Since the first two rows have account type of Principal it gets added in the principal type while the third row is of type Interest hence it gets added to interest_type with key being currency and the value being Principal or Interest depending on the type

Comment: Seems like a "group by" of sorts - might be able to find other questions / examples from such.

Answer (score 2):

> you can try this way spark

```
scala> var dfdd = Seq((123,"USD","Principal" ,1000,100),(123,"EUR","Principal",2000,50),(123,"USD","Interest",2000,100)).toDF("ID","currency","account_name","principal","interest")

scala> dfdd.show()
+---+--------+------------+---------+--------+
| ID|currency|account_name|principal|interest|
+---+--------+------------+---------+--------+
|123|     USD|   Principal|     1000|     100|
|123|     EUR|   Principal|     2000|      50|
|123|     USD|    Interest|     2000|     100|
+---+--------+------------+---------+--------+
scala> var dfdd2 = dfdd.groupBy("ID","account_name").pivot("currency").agg(collect_list("principal"))
+---+------------+------+------+
| ID|account_name|   EUR|   USD|
+---+------------+------+------+
|123|    Interest|    []|[2000]|
|123|   Principal|[2000]|[1000]|
+---+------------+------+------+
//added .show() only for understanding purpose
scala> var dfdd3 = dfdd2.withColumn("account_type",struct($"account_name",$"EUR",$"USD")).drop("EUR","USD","account_name").groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("account_type").as("test"))


scala> dfdd3.toJSON.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id":123,"test":[{"account_name":"Interest","EUR":[],"USD":[2000]},{"account_name":"Principal","EUR":[2000],"USD":[1000]}]}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

equal JSON format as your desired output 
[image]

have look do let me know if you have any question related to same

Comment: instead of the array structure is it possible to get the structure that i mentioned above in the comment so that the key is currency and value is numerical number

Comment: ya got you questions, but I am  using here collect_set so it will always give result as an Array.